# Hyper V Linux website hosting & opening in network windows systems

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine

I have  just started learning Linux on my own. I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 desktop version & installed lamp server also...

I have installed apache GUI & created virtual hosts example.com & configured the hosts file with domain & ip.

Now it's working fine on virtual, but I want to access the same on windows network also.

Answer (score 0):

Finally achieved this...

Ubuntu  (test2016.com)

create folder in /var/www of your website..

edit host file & add newly created website...

run a2nsite & follow the screen...

window server
go to dns & create new zone & point it to ubuntu ip..

:)